# Error while executing batch insert in TDengine

Tags: sql, database

I'm using TDengine database to process IoT data.

The statement for creating table:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS stock_basic (
    list_date TIMESTAMP, 
    ts_code NCHAR(10), 
    symbol NCHAR(6), 
    name NCHAR(6), 
    area NCHAR(6), 
    industry NCHAR(6), 
    fullname NCHAR(256), 
);
```

When I execute it, there is an error: Timestamp data out of range.

I don't know how to check it.

Comment: "Batch insert" (from the title) is causing the error, isn't it? If so, I guess you should post it as well. CREATE TABLE isn't enough (BTW, how can it raise *timestamp out of range*? Which range?).

Answer (score 1):

I met "Timestamp data out of range", but not in the step of create tables. I met "Timestamp data out of range" while i was trying to insert data into the tables. This error is usually caused by the property of the database.You can use

`show databases\G;`
to see like below

```
*************************** 7.row ***************************
        name: db
created_time: 2022-01-06 14:10:13.182
     ntables: 1
     vgroups: 1
     replica: 1
      quorum: 1
        days: 10
        keep: 3650
   cache(MB): 16
      blocks: 6
     minrows: 100
     maxrows: 4096
    wallevel: 1
       fsync: 3000
        comp: 2
   cachelast: 0
   precision: ms
      update: 0
      status: ready
```

There is an property called "keep", this parameters controls the earliest time stamp that is allow in your insert clause. In my example, the earliest timestamp should be 3650 * 24 * 3600 * 1000 millisecond. You can insert timestamp earlier than 3650 days ago from now on.
You can check whether you timestamp is within "keep" or not.